# How to filter data in excel and use it in calculations?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

So the setup I would like is:

- Sheet 1: the data (aka database)
- Sheet 2: where we have the criteria for the filtering and also run various formulas/calculations on the returned filtered results
- Sheet 3: displays the data from sheet 2 in a nicer format
- Sheet 4: possibly a sheet where the filtered results get copied to

I'd like to avoid VBA if possible as I don't want to be the only one that can maintain it.

So far we've tried using Advanced filtering and copying the results to another sheet, but it doesn't update automatically (which seems to require VBA or a macro).

We have a lot of formulas to run on the filtered results so doing a bunch of IF or INDEX formulas isn't practical and would be a nightmare to maintain.

Ideally theres one place to alter the "Query" that returns the filtered rows. Then we run calculations on those filtered results.

I'm really surprised something simple like this is hard to do (or at least hard to find information on). Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thank you!

Comment: Excel is not a database. For database functionality... use a database ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin I hear ya and I wish I could! Work is making me do this in Excel. Hoping to get it acting a little like one if possible.

Comment: I've always found soup difficult to eat with a fork... wish you luck ;)

Comment: This is really too broad, ambiguous, and open-ended for people here to give you useful advice within the limitations of the Q&A format.  There isn't a definitive right answer based on the available information, and tossing out random ideas in comments won't get you anywhere fast unless you're lucky.  You might try getting some general advice in our all-purpose chat room (see Root Access at the top of the chat rooms list from the link at the bottom of the page).  If you can better define this, provide some screenshots or mockups, and a focused question, that would be a better fit.

Comment: @John_911, you need dynamic link between Source and Filtered data, to get  updates. I can suggest you Non-VBA solution for that. ☺

Answer (score 0):

> Ideally theres one place to alter the "Query" that returns the filtered rows.

This can't be done and meet your no-VBA criterion. The only ways to manipulate an in-place filter requires either VBA or at least some clicking in the UI.

Your best bet is to use a true database application instead. Excel is useful for analyzing data but is not the correct tool for performing complicated queries against your data.